# Azure Data Factory read url values from csv and copy to sql database

Tags: url, copy, metadata, azure-data-factory

I am quite new in ADF so thats why i am asking you for any suggestions.

The use case:
I have a csv file which contains unique id and url's (see image below). i would like to use this file in order to export the value from various url's. In the second image you can see a example of the data from a url.

So in the current situation i am using each url and insert this manually as a source from the ADF Copy Activity task to export the data to a SQL DB. This is very time consuming method.

How can i create a ADF pipeline to use the csv file as a source, and that a copy activity use each row of the url and copy the data to Azure SQL DB? Do i need to add GetMetaData activity for example? so how?

Many thanks.

[image: a csv file]

[image: a xml file]

Answer (score 0):

use a look up activity that reads all the data,Then use a foreach loop which reads line by line.Inside foreach use a copy activity where u can able to copy response to the sink.

Comment: thanks for your response but what would be my Source in the Copy Data activity of the Foreach ?

Comment: Source -look up activity output count(number of rows of lookup activity output)

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy XML response of URL, we can use **HTTP** linked service with XML dataset.  As @BeingReal said, Lookup activity should be used to refer the table which contains all the URLs and inside for each activity, Give the copy activity with HTTP as source and sink as per the requirement. I tried to repro the same in my environment. Below are the steps.

- Lookup table with 3 URLs are taken as in below image.

[image]

- For-each activity is added in sequence with Lookup activity.
  [image]
- Inside For-each, Copy activity is added. Source is given as HTTP linked service.
  [image]
- In HTTP linked service, base URL, `@item().name` is given. **name** is the column that stored URLs in the lookup table. Replace the **name** with the column name that you gave in lookup table.
  [image]
- In Sink, azure database is given. (Any sink of your requirement is to be used). Data is copied to SQL database.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thanks for your response but i still have error that came from the ForEach activity.  I used a HTTP Dataset as a source in  Copy Activity. The error

Comment: Share the error screenshot or error message

Answer (score 0):

**this is the dataset HTTP inside the copy activity**

[image]

**This is the input of the Copy Activity inside the for each**

[image]

**this is the output of the Copy Activity**

[image]

**My sink is A Azure SQL Database without any tables yet. i would like to create auto table on the fly from ADF. Dont understand why this error came up**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the baseURL setting